# time date format is not matching in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to extract the date from a timestamp column of a CSV file. But it is showing an error: `( time data '1/29/2019 3:30:00.000000000 PM'` does not match format `'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p')`.

```py
datetime.strptime(my_string,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p")
```

I have attached the screenshot of the CSV file.

[image: csv file screenshot]

Comment: "%I:" should be changed to "%H:"

Comment: Yes @Redline I have just pasted the error.

Comment: Ok, try using the code in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because `%f` expects a max of 6 digits.

> When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right. %f is an extension to the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available).

But in your example there are 9 zeros.

One work around will be to three 0's to your format string.

```
>>> x
'1/29/2019 3:30:00.000000000 PM'
>>> datetime.strptime('1/29/2019 3:30:00.000000000 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f000 %p')
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 3, 30)
>>> datetime.strptime('1/29/2019 3:30:00.000000000 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f000 %p')
datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 29, 15, 30)
```

Comment: That is correct only if numbers found in the CSV only have 000 in the end

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
datetime.strptime(my_string,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %p")
```

Here's the more detailed explanation of your specific case:

> **%I** = Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 01, 02, …,
>   12
>   **%H** = Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. 00, 01,
>   …, 23

In the moment that your input file presents a 24-hour clock format time your code will throw an error, because you are using **%I**.

Changing to **%H** should solve the error.

Here's a link to the complete strptime syntax for Python 2:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

And Python 3:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

**Edit**
%f works with microseconds (6 zeroes) but you have 9.
Because of rounding problems my suggestion is to cut out the last 3 digits from your number.

Here's a possible solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_string = "1/29/2019 3:30:00.000000000 PM"
my_string_split = my_string.split()
my_string = my_string_split[0] + " " + my_string_split[1][:-3] + " " + my_string_split[2]
print (datetime.strptime(my_string,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p") )
```

**Output**

```
2019-01-29 15:30:00
```

Comment: But the given data is for 12 hour clock.I tried to change it to %H.It's still showing error.

Comment: And when I an using the same format in pandas it's working fine.

Comment: Wrote a new solution